# What makes this single-feature linear regression perform poorly?

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am testing with single-feature linear regression implemented by gradient descent adapted from the  tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-gradient-descent-97a6c8700931

The implementation is straightforward, with weights updated following the gradient (so-called gradient descent).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)


x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100) # 1000 values between 0 and 100
y = 0.4*x + 3



#Preprocessing Input data
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
# Building the model
m = 0
c = 0

L = 0.001  # The learning Rate
epochs = 10  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent


n = float(len(x)) # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    y_pred = m*x + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    cost=np.sum(np.square(y - y_pred))
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(x * (y - y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(y - y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    print("Cost: {}, m: {}, c: {}\n".format(cost, m, c))

    
print (m, c)
```

And I got

```
Cost: 66502.69360269362, m: 2.980134680134681, c: 0.04600000000000002

Cost: 2154894.319611961, m: -14.012236408983222, c: -0.20610546801346816

Cost: 70050303.28853585, m: 82.87521068285723, c: 1.241530383820881

Cost: 2277388248.5411315, m: -469.56062336187455, c: -7.002473745232483

Cost: 74039836741.10417, m: 2680.334036437331, c: 40.01359353844544

Cost: 2407098544049.198, m: -15279.827701739041, c: -228.05383729236456

Cost: 78256836757675.23, m: 87125.94814145382, c: 1300.4310405561246

Cost: 2544196836061482.0, m: -496774.302711737, c: -7414.71863567037

Cost: 8.271401974355902e+16, m: 2832525.2415301367, c: 42277.587072774666

Cost: 2.6891036751423396e+18, m: -16150572.367496913, c: -241059.4462543846

-16150572.367496913 -241059.4462543846
```

It certainly diverges. Expected results are around 0.4 and 3. What is wrong with this code?

The plot from the code (which shows the dataset) is here:

[image]

Comment: The linked example does have a smaller `L` and larger `epochs` than your first attempt; your second attempt shows a decent fit indeed, with better `L` and `epochs`. That's one issue.

Comment: You should also plot your data, and the overlying fit: the fit may be more accurate than you think, because you *don't have error estimates* for the two fitted parameters. And your data consists of only 100 points (despite the comment), with each point an error up to +/- 10. Given that y without errors would range from 3 to 43, those are large errors, adding to uncertainty in the final fit results. Don't expect the fit to retrieve your input parameters that accurately.

Comment: You simply need to decrease `L` and increase `epochs`. When I try with `L = 0.0001` and `epochs = 100000`, I get decent results. Note that original exampe enotebook also has `L = 0.0001`, just `epochs = 1000`, but the latter may depend on the input data, but I don't think it is mentioned how those data (in `data.csv`) are generated, so these may have much smaller errors.